# How to access firebase-functions environment configuration from Cloud Run

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I'm migrating a Firebase Function to Cloud Run. Everything is working as expected so far, including the Firebase Hosting link (which is great!). I'm just not sure how I should read the environment variables I've configured for this project (via https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env).

Comment: What values are you particularly interested in?

Comment: I’m interested in custom values that I set myself — eg. the API key for a web service that I’m talking to. I don’t know how much integration with Firebase is planned, but since Cloud Run works with Firebase Hosting, a way to share runtime config would be useful to folks like me who’d like to use both Functions & Run (or migrate from one to the other) within the same project.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to find a different way to configure Cloud Run.  You won't be able to access your environment variables set for Cloud Functions when deployed with the Firebase CLI.  Those variables are only accessible for code running in Cloud Functions that uses the "firebase-functions" module.

Instead, you should set your Cloud Run environment with gcloud [as documented here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables).

Comment: Since Firebase's environment config is based on the Google Cloud Runtime Configuration API, I assume we could also use that to directly access config - (I've just successfully read values via the services described here: https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/runtime-configurator). But I assume there are disadvantages to this - 1) doesn't create revisions of the Cloud Run instance on change, 2) isn't injected into the environment & so requires additional runtime api request